# How to replace existing labels instead of adding more

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jlabel

I'm trying to make a program which outputs a 8x8 grid with each cell being a random colour once the button is pressed. I've got it to work, but now when I press the button twice, instead of replacing all the cells with another random colour, it creates another 8x8 grid right next to it. It makes sense why it does this from the way i've implemented it but I want to replace each cell not create more and I'm not sure how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Pictures:

https://gyazo.com/282de6b6e324b246d23378052365efbe (the way it should be)
https://gyazo.com/7d9884be75957c4d50c8fc28c24f8f05 (2nd button press)

Comment: Ok, we have the pictures, but... the code?

Comment: A little hesitant to make the code public as its part of an assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I want to replace each cell

Don't replace the components.

Instead just change the existing components.

So instead of your looping code creating the new components. Your looping code will update the existing components. So you just change the property of each cell by using setBackground() or setIcon() or whatever method you use to set the color.